# Adding an Application (NOT tab) to a page

Tags: php, facebook

I use an application added to a Facebook page to subscribe to real-time updates which has worked fine and still works fine. However, the old way of adding an application to the page using add.php seems to redirect to the dialog for adding pagetabs now.

Add.php: https://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=XXX&pages=1&next=URL

This no longer works and redirects to:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?api_key=XXX&next=URL

This would be fine if we could use the application on the page without displaying an empty pagetab on the wall.

So does anyone know of any changes to this process and a new way to add an application to a page as an application and not a pagetab? Will this require using the Graphi API and manage_pages permission to do it or is there a simple URL method we can follow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct way to add an Application to a page that is not a page tab.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs/

Basically the old add.php method has been removed but you can still add applications that do not contain a pagetab to a page by making the following call:

> POST: /{page-id}/tabs
>
> app_id = {app-id}
>
> is_permanent = false

you need the **page** access token to do this.

Further information can be found in the bug report here: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/779220265438820/

Thanks to Pragati on that bug report who pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

This is no longer possible to do.

You can get part of the way there with [Open Graph objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph), but they don't give you any ability to run code on the page and are restricted to particular display typesl

Comment: Is there any reference to the removal of this feature? I guess following on from this, how on earth are we to get an application to a page for real-time updates now? Are they or have they changed this process already of subscribing to a pages updates? and Thanks.

Comment: Seem to have found something on this now, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/ with subscriptions to pages being handled within the graph api for the app and not based on assigning an app to a page it seems.

Comment: Real-time updates are updates of user data **to** your application. i.e. if the user posts a new update, your application can sign up to receive notifications whenever they do. It's *not* a way to push updates to a user's page. If people want updates, they Like/Subscribe to your page.

Comment: The question was real time updates for pages not users. Facebook questions never go down well on here.

Comment: The question isn't particularly clear. Plenty of Facebook questions do fine around here.